# Codeception Unit testing [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method UnitTester::haveRecord

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, codeception

I am new in Codeception trying to run a sample unit test in my Laravel framework but getting the following error:

```
[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method UnitTester::haveRecord
```

And following code I have tried to run using Codeception:

```
 <?php namespace Article;
 use App\Article;
 use Faker\Factory as Faker;
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 class SaveTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
/**
 * @var \UnitTester
 */
protected $tester;

protected function _before()
{
}

protected function _after()
{
}

// tests
public function testSomeFeature()
{
    $faker= Faker::create('App/Article');

        $title = $faker->sentence;
        $content = implode($faker->paragraphs(5));
        $created_at = Carbon::now();
        $updated_at = Carbon::now();


        $this->tester->haveRecord( 'Article',   ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content,'created_at' => $created_at,'updated_at' => $updated_at]);


         $this->tester->seeRecord('articles',['title' => $title,'content' => $content,'created_at' => $created_at,'updated_at' => $updated_at]);




}
}
```

Could please help me out of this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you enabled Laravel5 module in unit.suite.yml ?

Comment: Wasn't enabled, after your question did it now error resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue resolved after I have enabled Laravel5 module in unit.suite.yml

The unit.suite.yml file format with Laravel5 module:

```
actor: UnitTester
modules:
 enabled:
    - Asserts
    - Laravel5:
        part: ORM
    - \Helper\Unit
```